# When I use TimeBarrier.SUNRISE_CODE as the first parameter in the method inSunriseOrSunsetPeriod getting barrier result false always in HMS

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

In HMS Time Awareness if I use **TimeBarrier.SUNRISE_CODE** as the first parameter in the method  **inSunriseOrSunsetPeriod** always  getting barrier result **false**. How can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet for checking ? This problem may related with the time frame or the local time zone you are in.

Comment: //define the barrier
        long oneHourMilliSecond = 60 * 60 * 1000L;

        AwarenessBarrier inSunsetPeriod = TimeBarrier.inSunriseOrSunsetPeriod(TimeBarrier.SUNSET_CODE,
                15* oneHourMilliSecond, 23 * oneHourMilliSecond);